# Rails CRUD Buttons for all views using single Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view, crud

Rails newbie here.

I would like to use a single partial to create my CRUD buttons on all views, regardless of controller. So this is what I have working so far. In my controller I have:

**information_controller.rb**

```
class InformationController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set

  def set
    #Set Paths
    @new_path = new_information_path
    @edit_path = edit_information_path
  end

  #Then normal index, show, etc definitions follows

end
```

I will take the index and edit pages as an example.

**index.html.haml**

```
-@operation = "index" #To let partial know what page it is in
-render 'form', operation: @operation
```

**edit.html.haml**

```
-@operation = "edit"
- render 'form', operation: @operation
```

Then, in my partial form I have:

**_form.html.haml**

```
.form-inputs
  .container-fluid
    .span8
      .simple_form_for @foo do |f|
        =f.input :title, as: :string
        =render 'controls', f: f, operation: @operation
```

and in my controls form which serves only to display CRUD buttons regardless of the controller, I have:

**_controls.html.haml**

```
-if(operation=="new")
  link_to "Create", @new_path, class: "btn btn-success"
-else
  -if(operation=="edit")
    =f.submit "Update"
  -else
    .span3
      %table
        %tr
          %td=link_to "Edit", @edit_path(f), class: "btn btn-primary"
          %td=link_to "Delete", f, confirm: "Are you sure", method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

So this works well for the index page which loads 'edit, delete and create' buttons. But I do not know how I can properly assign edit_information_path in the controller to @edit_path because that requires an edit parameter 'f'.

The assignment @new_path = new_information_path works, but @edit_path requires 'f'. Any tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
link_to "Edit",{:controller => params[:controller], :action => :edit, :id => f.object.id}, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

or:

```
link_to "Edit",{:controller => controller_name, :action => :edit, :id => f.object.id}, class: "btn btn-primary"
```